# Laravel: the count in the condition always returns 0

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have two tables, one named **Clients** and the other named **Projects** linked together *via a foreign key* (this is client_id, present in Projects).

In the view related to the list of all clients, I have an additional field that shows me the number of active projects for each client.

To do this I have run the following condition:

`$count_project = Project::select('client_id')->where('client_id','$client->id')->count();`

`return view('client.index', compact('clients', 'count_project'));`

```js
public function index()
    {
        $clients = Client::all();
        $count_project = Project::select('client_id')->where('client_id','$client->id')->count();
        return view('client.index', compact('clients', 'count_project'));
    }
```

where in the last line I pass the variable to the corresponding view.

There is certainly an error in the condition written above.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: You have '$client_id' .... should not be quoted. You are saying give me the records where the client_id is the string '$client_id'

Comment: Then? I'm new. I would like to try to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are getting a collection of clients, not a single client.  Assuming you have the relationship setup, a cleaner way is

```
        $clients = Client::withCount('projects')->get();

        return view('client.index', compact('clients'));
```

now each client, when you loop over them will have an extra attribute `projects_count`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: It is not clear to me. Can you explain it more simply please? I am new in Laravel.
However `$clients = Client::all();` is used to call all clients (from the Clients table) and display them in a table in the view.
While `$count_project` is used to retrieve the number of projects for each client.

Comment: You are looping over the clients in the view?  And using like {{ $client->name }}, yes?  Now with the query mentioned, you can do {{ $client->projects_count }}.  Your original query suggested that you wanted the count of projects per client - not a single value

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: ok ok yes. It's the name that was confusing me. All clear. Perfect

Comment: How can I find this information? that is, I absolutely did not know the withCount method